# Customizing Title and Description using Facebook Share in an IFrame

Tags: facebook, iframe, share, facebook-iframe

I've created that is hosted on my home site, and included on 3 individual sites via IFrame. After the poll is completed, we would like to give pollers the ability to share their results via Facebook online. The Facebook share requires meta tags to manipulate the title and description. What would be the best way to complete this objective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you dont use the stream.publish method of JSDK?

```
      FB.ui({
method: 'stream.publish',
message:'your result description',
attachment: {
  name: title,

  caption: "My Result",
  media: [{
    type: 'image',
    href: 'http://www.example.com/',
    src: 'http://www.example/images/working.jpeg'
  }]
},
action_links: [{
  text: 'Join the Run',
  href: 'http://www.example.com/'
}],
  user_message_prompt: 'Tell your friends about Get your percentage:'
});
```

I think this is also a good way to share with friends.